# Outlook 2013 calendar SharePoint 2013 integration

Tags: 2013, outlook, sharepoint-calendar, synchronisation

I'm trying synchronize the calendar from Outlook 2013 to SharePoint 2013.
In SharePoint 2010 this was easy, just overlay calendar for team group.

But, in SharePoint 2013 it is harder. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Overlay is still possible, but you need Exchange 2013 for full integration. Hope this helps!

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/synchronize-sharepoint-content-with-outlook-HA102774420.aspx

Comment: The link is no longer valid.